# How to set up a guard at the state level in AASM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

Is there a way to define a guard (eg `has_legs?`) that is checked before entering a state (eg `running`) in any event?

In the list of all possible callbacks there are guards for events and transitions, but not for events.

I tried to do a conditional validation for the model. It worked in the event execution, but not for aasm methods (eg `may_run?`).

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a build in method. I would use a workaround with a Hash containing the default options.

```ruby
DEFAULT_EVENT_OPTS = { guard: ... }
DEFAULT_TRANSITION_OPTS = { ... }

event :clean, DEFAULT_EVENT_OPTS.merge({ ... }) do
  transitions DEFAULT_TRANSITION_OPTS.merge({:from => :running, :to => :cleaning, :guard => :cleaning_needed?})
end
```